# can someone explain this behavior of StringBuffer?

Tags: stringbuffer

```
public class StrBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  //5
        sb.append("hello"); //6
        foo(sb); //7
        System.out.println(sb); //8
    }

    private static void foo(StringBuffer sb) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sb.append("wow");    //1
        sb = new StringBuffer();  //2
        sb.append("foo"); //3
        System.out.println(sb); //4     
    }
}
```

in the above when i print in line8. output is "hellowow" .... can some one explain this please?

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: I read that String Buffere uses same memory to modify the string in it. So, at line 2 when it creates new instance and at line 3 and 4 "foo" is printed, but when it went back to line 8 "hellowow" is printed.  part i don't get is if sb lo local to foo method "wow" still persist when we come back to line8

Comment: After looking below explanation i got it lurker thank you.

Comment: I would encourage you to read Jon Skeet's article on Java parameter passing: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html .

Comment: Thanks Brian, i will definitely read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you pass a reference to main's sb to foo.
In foo, you append "wow" to the referenced object.

Then, in foo, you create a new StringBuffer object, and change the local sb to point to it.

It might be clearer if I rename the reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  //5
    sb.append("hello"); //6
    foo(sb); //7
    System.out.println(sb); //8
}

private static void foo(StringBuffer ref) {
    ref.append("wow");    //1
    ref = new StringBuffer();  //2
    ref.append("foo"); //3
    System.out.println(ref); //4     
}
```

'ref', as passed in to foo, is a just a reference to main's sb.  You can operate on ref (ie., sb) in foo until you changed ref to refer to a different object.

Comment: You should consider marking your question answered, then!

Answer (score 3):

```
    sb.append("wow");    //1
```

You just mutated the `StringBuffer` instance you passed in.

```
    sb = new StringBuffer();  //2
```

You just assigned your local parameter to point to a new `StringBuffer` instance.  This has no effect on the caller or on the old instance.

Comment: Thnka you, sb is still local at line 1 and that change is persisted at line8 - this part i'm not getting.

Comment: can you let me know if my thinking is correct. upto line 1 sb is still old referece and what ever changes will be persisted. when i created new instance then sb will be considered as local ?

Comment: @LeanJava: It's not the fact that it's local or not; it's simply a matter of which _instance_ you're changing.